# VMWare-hosted FreeBSD 12 server DHCP resets, won't route again without running /etc/rc.d/routing restart

Tags: routing, dhcp, freebsd

My cloud host provider has an issue where DHCP keeps being reset. They say they're working on it. It results in a short network blip. I have the same problem if I reset DHCP myself using the command `/etc/rc.d/routing restart`.

In the meantime, every time it resets I need to log in and manually run `/etc/rc.d/routing restart`.

Here's the network config.

```
hostname="[redacted]"
ifconfig_vmx0="DHCP"
static_routes="gw"
route_gw="10.255.255.1 -iface vmx0"
defaultrouter="10.255.255.1"
dumpdev="AUTO"
```

I'm hoping there is some setting I am overlooking that should fix this. Is there a way to configure the routing script to run after the DHCP script? The not-smart way to do this would be to check if there is a routing issue with `ping` or `host` or another networking command, but I'd rather the OS handle this.